# MySQL server has gone away

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi, web.py

I've recently moved from my local web.py/apache setup to a shared host
and I'm trying to match my home configuration.  One issue that is
popping up is an OperationalError "MySQL server has gone away".
Searching around the internet, people who come across this error
tended to be inactive for the space of hours.  This happens to me
between seconds.

I've confirmed using mod_wsgi's application() function example that I
am in fact running in daemon mode.  One issue though, that concerns me
is that if I spit out web.ctx.orm to the error log, it appears to be a
new object for each request.  Shouldn't my sqlalchemy session object be the same
between page requests?

Here's my python code and a portion of my apache setup.  Is there
anything that would cause problems on this new machine I hadn't had
before on my home machine?

```
def load_sqla(handler):
    web.ctx.orm = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    try:
        try:
            return handler()
        except web.HTTPError:
            web.ctx.orm.commit()
            raise
        except:
            web.ctx.orm.rollback()
            raise
    finally:
        web.ctx.orm.commit()
        # If the above alone doesn't work, uncomment
        # the following line:
        web.ctx.orm.expunge_all()

... urls and controllers ...

app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
app.add_processor(load_sqla)
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

and here's a portion of my apache setup.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app processes=1 threads=1 python-path=/home/net/
public_html/myapp
WSGIProcessGroup app
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/net/public_html/myapp/managio.py
<Directory "/home/stratton/public_html/myapp">
 Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: As suggested, switching to NullPool for the engine solved the problem.  While this might not be a permanent solution, it certainly alleviates the issues on development until I need to switch to high-traffic production and I can spend time of the server configuration issues themselves.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs at: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

Setting `processes=1` actually leaves multiprocessing on, which may be why you're getting concurrent access to the same sql connection.

Also it appears you're using SQLAlchemy, so maybe try turning on QueuePool or NullPool use when you make your engine?

Comment: In this case the use of 'processes=1' and the subsequent setting of 'wsgi.multiprocess' flag to True when not really wouldn't make any difference. It also doesn't result in multiprocessing being left on, at least not in mod_wsgi. The only difference is whether that flag is set True or not.